# Overriding methods in JavaScript with constructor property

Tags: javascript

Is this a good/safe cross-browser way to implement method overriding in JavaScript? :

```
function Person(firstName, lastName)
{
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
};

Person.prototype.sayHi = function()
{
  return "Hi, my name is " + this.firstName;
};

function Employee(firstName, lastName, position)
{
  Person.call(this, firstName, lastName);
  this.position = position;
};

Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

Employee.prototype.sayHi = function()
{
  return this.constructor.prototype.sayHi() + " I'm a " + this.position;
}
```

I could also write:

```
Employee.prototype.sayHi = function()
{
  return Person.prototype.sayHi() + " I'm a " + this.position;
}
```

but with this solution I'm refering to direct method, or

```
Employee.prototype.sayHi = function()
{
  return this.__proto__.sayHi() + " I'm a " + this.position;
}
```

but this one is awful and not crossbrowser.

**EDIT: I assumed Object.create is crossbrowser as I can use a shim**

Comment: There is no such thing as "method overloading" in JavaScript. I think you mean "overriding" in this case, but there is also no such thing in JS.

Comment: sorry, typo: overriding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on the `constructor` property of the `prototype` to call parent functions because normally, that property should point to the children constructor.

```
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;
```

There are a few other ways to access parent functions safely, like referring to the `parent` prototype directly like you are trying to do in your second example, however there's something wrong with the way you are doing it.

If you call `sayHi` without using `call` or `apply`, `this` will point to `Person.prototype` during the function call and that's not what you want.
You should call `sayHi` by setting the context object to the current employee instance, like this:

```
Employee.prototype.sayHi = function() {
  return Person.prototype.sayHi.call(this) + " I'm a " + this.position;
};
```

Another way of doing this would be to store a reference to the parent prototype in the children prototype.

```
 Employee.prototype.super = Person.prototoype;

 Employee.prototype.sayHi = function() {
    return this.super.sayHi.call(this) + " I'm a " + this.position;
 };
```

Another interesting approach I've seen is to wrap every function of the children prototype in a function that dynamically sets a reference to the parent function on the object instance, so that you can only use `this.parent()` to call the function. However I would not recommend this solution since it will reduce performances and increase memory usage.

I have created a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tke3E/)** to demonstrate that concept.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> ```
> Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
> ```

[`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is not supported by older browsers, but you can shim it.

> ```
> Employee.prototype.sayHi = function() {
>     return this.constructor.prototype.sayHi() + " I'm a " + this.position;
> }
> ```

I wouldn't use that. You expect `this.constructor` to be the `Person` from which you inherited from, but that might not be the case. Actually it would be good practise to set the `Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee`, which would cause recursion with a stack overflow to your method.

Instead, you should explicitly refer to the function you want to use:

```
return Person.prototype.sayHi.call(this) + " I'm a " + this.position;
```

If you want it dynamically, you'd use

```
return Object.getPrototypeOf(Employee.prototype).sayHi.call(this) + " I'm a " + this.position;
```

but notice that [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) is not supported in older browsers. So if you need a cross-browser and DRY way, use the module pattern:

```
(function(proto, super) {
     proto.sayHi = function() {
         return super.sayHi.call(this) + " I'm a " + this.position;
     };
     …
})(Employee.prototype, Person.prototype);
```

or the revealing prototype pattern:

```
Employee.prototype = (function(super) {
     var proto = Object.create(super);
     proto.sayHi = function() {
         return super.sayHi.call(this) + " I'm a " + this.position;
     };
     …
     return proto;
})(Person.prototype);
```