# Javascript __proto__ output

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Below are some examples showcasing the different behaviors of prototypal inheritance based on how the objects are defined and created.  I distinguish between the "prototype property" of an object, e.g. `someObject.prototype` and the "prototype reference" (which I think should refer to the object from which `someObject` inherits?).

### Example 1

This seems to be the way to preserve the parent object's prototype property.  Isn't this the recommended way of inheriting?

```
// create object whose prototype reference is Object; add stuff.
var Parent = Object.create(Object);
Parent.a = "1";
Parent.f = function() { return true; };

// add stuff to prototype property
Parent.prototype.b = 1;
Parent.prototype.g = function() { return false; };

// create an object whose prototype reference is Parent (??)
var Child = Object.create(Parent);

console.log(Parent.__proto__)  // [Function: Object]
console.log(Parent.prototype)  // { b: 1, g: [Function] }
console.log(Child.__proto__)   // { a: '1', f: [Function] }
console.log(Child.prototype)   // { b: 1, g: [Function] }
```

1. I would have expected `Child.__proto__` to be something naming  `Parent` in the same way `Parent.__proto__` names `Object`.
2. We see that `Child`'s prototype reference points to the properties of `Parent` rather than the properties of `Parent.prototype`.  This is counterintuitive, to me at least, as I would have expected to see `Parent.prototype`'s properties `b` and `g` instead.

### Example 2

Mixed results.

```
// use a constructor instead.
var Parent = function () {
    this.a = "1";
    this.f = function() { return true; };
}

// again, add stuff to prototype property.
Parent.prototype.b = 1;
Parent.prototype.g = function() { return false; };

// create an object whose prototype reference is Parent (??)
var Child = new Parent();

// create differently
var Sibling = Object.create(Parent);

console.log(Parent.__proto__)   // [Function: Empty]
console.log(Parent.prototype)   // { b: 1, g: [Function] }

console.log(Child.__proto__)    // { b: 1, g: [Function] }
console.log(Child.prototype)    // undefined

console.log(Sibling.__proto__)  // [Function]
console.log(Sibling.prototype)  // { b: 1, g: [Function] }
```

1. Here, `Child`'s prototype references `Parents.prototype`'s properties.  This is what I expected above?
2. On the other hand, `Sibling`'s prototype reference is now a function, which is the prototype reference of `Parent`.

### Example 3

This seems to be the way to preserve the parent object's prototype reference, but you lose its prototype property.

```
// create object constructor; add stuff.
var Parent = function () {
    this.a = "1";
    this.f = function() { return true; };
}

// add stuff to prototype property.
Parent.prototype.b = 1;
Parent.prototype.g = function() { return false; };

// create an object whose prototype reference is Parent (??)
var Child = function() {
    this.c = "2";
};

// supposed Ad-hoc prototype inheritance
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)

console.log(Parent.__proto__)  // [Function: Empty]
console.log(Parent.prototype)  // { b: 1, g: [Function] }
console.log(Child.__proto__)   // [Function: Empty]
console.log(Child.prototype)   // {}
```

Is the method shown in **Example 1** preferred since you have access to both the parent's prototype property, its own properties as well as `Object`'s properties/methods?  I've read in other posts that some of these ways of inheriting should be equal...which is not true.  Also, I've read other posts, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance?lq=1), that **Example 3** is the way to go.  Or perhaps I am just not sure what `__proto__` stands for...

Thanks for any clarification you might have for the differences between these mix and match situations!

Comment: Regarding your title: there is no `__prototype__` :-)

Comment: Great question, especially for a low-rep user. (ran out of votes so can't +1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I distinguish between the "prototype member" of an object, e.g. someObject.prototype and the "prototype reference"

Good terminology, and distinguishing them is the first step in understanding them [and the difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572).

> (which I think should refer to the object from which someObject inherits?).

Exactly. In contrast to the `.prototype` member, you acess the protypte reference via [`Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) or the non-standard `.__proto__` property.

> Example 1
>
> Isn't this the recommended way of inheriting?

It's *one* way to do inheritance, and the most pure form of prototypical inheritance. Notice that `Parent` and `Child` are plain objects, no constructor functions are involved.

> ```
> // create object whose prototype reference is Object; add stuff.
> var Parent = Object.create(Object);
> ```

That's the first mistake: You're inheriting from the `Object` *function* (which is based on the constructor pattern, see below). You should just do

```
var Parent = {};
// or
var Parent = Object.create(Object.prototype);
```

> ```
> // add stuff to prototype member
> Parent.prototype.b = 1;
> Parent.prototype.g = function() { return false; };
> ```

Yet, the `.prototype` member is of no significance in this model of inheritance. It's just a normal property, in this case one inherited from `Object`. You're actually modifying the `Object.prototype` object here (big no-no)!

> ```
> // create an object whose prototype reference is Parent (??)
> var Child = Object.create(Parent);
> ```

Yes, that's what [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) does.

> [Example 1 / 1] I would have expected Child.**proto** to be something naming Parent in the same way Parent.**proto** names Object.

It names `Object` only because that is a named function. There's no way to know the variable name `Parent` from the object reference at runtime.

> [Example 1 / 2] We see that Child's prototype reference points to the members of Parent rather than the members of Parent.prototype. This is counterintuitive, to me at least, as I would have expected to see Parent.prototype's members b and g instead.

Yes, you're directly inheriting from the `Parent` object. `.prototype` is insignificant as stated above. `Child.prototype === Object.prototype` (it's inherited twice).

> Example 2 - use a constructor instead. Adding stuff to its prototype member.
>
> ```
> // create an object whose prototype reference is Parent (??)
> var Child = new Parent();
> ```
>
> [Example 2 / 1] Here, Child's prototype references Parents.prototype's members. This is what I expected above?

No. The [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) creates a prototype reference to the value of the `.prototype` member of the supplied constructor function - `Parent.prototype` in this case.

> ```
> // create differently
> var Sibling = Object.create(Parent);
> ```

Again, here you're creating an object that has a prototype reference to a function. Not what you want - instead use

```
var sibling = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Parent.call(sibling); // optionall apply the constructor on it, like `new` does
```

> [Example 2 / 2] On the other hand, Sibling's prototype reference is now a function,
>   which is the prototype reference of Parent.

To be more exact, it is the `Parent` function itself. That's why your `Sibling` does inherit a `.prototype` property.

> Example 3 - This seems to be the way to preserve the parent object's prototype reference, but you lose its prototype member:
>
> ```
> // supposed Ad-hoc prototype inheritance
> Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)
> ```

This is necessary to set up the inheritance (prototype reference) chain for the constructor way. It's the standard way to implement a "class" pattern in JavaScript.

> ```
> console.log(Parent.__proto__)  // [Function: Empty]
> console.log(Parent.prototype)  // { b: 1, g: [Function] }
> console.log(Child.__proto__)   // [Function: Empty]
> console.log(Child.prototype)   // {}
> ```

As you see here, both `Parent` and `Child` are functions - constructor functions to be exact. You would need to invoke them:

```
var childInstance = new Child();
console.log(childInstance) // {c: "2"}
console.log(childInstance.prototype) // undefined - it's not a constructor
console.log(childInstance.__proto__) // {} - the Child.prototype object
console.log(childInstance.__proto__.__proto__) // the Parent.prototype object
console.log(childInstance.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__) // the Object.prototype object
```

However, you forgot one step. `childInstance` does inherit `b` and `g` from `Parent.prototype`, but does not have the `a` and `f` proeprties created in the `Parent` constructor. For [correct inheritance in the constructor model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572) you also have to apply the `Parent` constructor on each instance, preferably inside the `Child` constructor:

```
function Child() {
    Parent.call(this);
    this.c = "2";
}
var childInstance = new Child();
console.log(childInstance) // {a: 1, f: [Function …], c: "2"}
```

Comment: Great post.  I think I have a much better understanding of what's going on now in terms of the objects and references...but I will keep reading!  The links you posted are interesting and led to many others.

Comment: Question:  In Example 3, can you also set the `Child`'s prototype inside the constructor like so? `var Child = function () { this.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype); Parent.call(this); }`

This way, everything is self contained?

Comment: No, inside the constructor `this` is the instance, not the constructor, and you'd need to set the prototype reference not some `.prototype` member. [Setting the `.prototype` in the constructor is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21296559/1048572), and [creating the instance in the constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24019863/1048572) is not how the `new`-pattern works.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what `Object.create` does, first you need to understand why it needs to do it.

The classic examples of prototyping in JavaScript makes the prototype be an instance of the inherited object:

```
function Parent(field) {
    this.field = field;
}

Parent.prototype.getField = function () { return this.field; }

function Child(field, field2) {
    Parent.call(this, field);
    this.field2 = field2;
}

Child.prototype = new Parent(null); // oops

Child.prototype.getField2 = function () { return this.field2; }
```

That "oops" line makes `Child.prototype` have a `field`, when we wanted it to only inherit the method `getField`.  You can guess this is not hygienic (language-wise), and it can get messy with less trivial examples.

A cleaner approach would be to instantiate a non-initialized `Parent`:

```
function inherit(parent) {
    function temp() {
    }
    temp.prototype = parent.prototype;
    return new temp();
}

Child.prototype = inherit(Parent);
```

The technique is to make a temporary constructor with the same prototype, such that when an object is created, no constructor initializations were done.  Effectively, only the prototype chain has been established.

Comment: notice that this is just what the OP does in the line `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)`

Comment: @Bergi, I know, and I think it's also the source of the OP's confusion or lack of knowledge.