# Same name for function and method, cannot call the former within the latter

Tags: javascript, scope, naming

I'm trying to use the same method name for both a function and a method (a function of an object) and calling the function from inside the method. However, the function does not get called at all. These are the relevant bits of the **function**:

```
function post(url, data, success, error) {

  console.log("Sending");      // This doesn't get even called

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();      // Nor a request is made

  // ... (more code here)
  }
```

And the relevant bits of the **method**

```
function u(parameter) {

  // ... more code here

  this.post = function(success, error) {     // post request

    this.on("submit", function(e) {     // Loop through all the nodes

      e.preventDefault();     // Stop the browser from sending a request

      console.log("Going to send your data");     // This works

      post(u(this).attr("action"), u(this).serialize(), success, error);     // Post the actual data

      console.log("Got here");     // Well it's async, but it also gets here
      });

    return this;
    }

  return this;
  }
```

It is supposed to be called from this **script** when the form is sent:

```
u("form").post(function(){
  alert("Yay, it worked");
  }, function(){
  alert("Something went wrong");
  });
```

It successfully calls the method and both of the messages are shown. However, the `Sending` from the function is NOT logged and no request is performed. I'm thinking either a problem with scope or with the function name being overwritten, but I'm not an expert here so any help would be appreciated. <strike>Why is the function post() not being called?. There's absolutely no error shown in the console.</strike>

After some testing, I can confirm **the problem is that they share the name. So, how could I have the same name shared for a method and a function?** The method would only be called like `u("form").post(callA, callB);` and the function like `post(url, data, callA, callB)l;`

Comment: Do you get any errors? Like a stack overflow?

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be in the body of your `u` function?  Hint: if you were to do something like `obj.u("form").post(...)` then `this` inside of the `u` body would be `obj`, if you are just doing `u("form").post(...)` then `this` will be the global object and assigning to `this.post` will overwrite the existing function.  Perhaps you should have `new` in there somewhere?

Comment: I expect it to be the in the scope of `u`, so `u.post()` would be one function and `post()` (or `window.post()`) would be a different function. But from your comment it seems my assumption was wrong. I'm gonna go back to test my assumptions (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your call of the `u` function that is problematic. You forgot the `new` keyword, which made the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) be the global scope object - on which you then are overwriting the global `post` variable.

Two fixes:

- Use `(new u("form")).post(…);` or make your constructor [`new`-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24019863/1048572)
- Don't put the `post` function in the global scope. Use the module pattern.

Comment: It took me a real while to understand the second part of your first fix, but now it's perfectly fixed with a *magic, do not touch* comment, thank you (;