# jQuery structure and understanding this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going through some pseudo-jquery code—and though I understand `this` for the most part, some of the implementations are confusing. I ran into this pseudocode, which is meant to explain how jQuery  works:

```
(function() {
  var foo = function(arg) { // core constructor
    // ensure to use the `new` operator
    if (!(this instanceof foo))
      return new foo(arg);
    // store an argument for this example
    this.myArg = arg;
    //..
  };

  // create `fn` alias to `prototype` property
  foo.fn = foo.prototype = {
    init: function () {/*...*/}
    //...
  };

  // expose the library
  window.foo = foo;
})();

// Extension:

foo.fn.myPlugin = function () {
  alert(this.myArg);
  return this; // return `this` for chainability
};

foo("bar").myPlugin(); // alerts "bar"
```

It isn't instantly obvious to me what `this` in `(!(this instance of foo))` or `this.myArg = arg;` is.

My initial impression is that this code is referenced every time an instance of `foo` is ran, i.e. `foo("bar").myPlugin();`.

Going off that assumption, `this` commonly refers to the object that owns the method, but in this case, if `foo` owns `this` (understanding that `foo` is pseudo for `jQuery`), `jQuery.myArg = arg` doesn't really make much sense. That would mean every time you invoke `foo` i.e. `foo("bar").myPlugin();` it instantiates `foo.bar` and to further the example at the bottom, `foo.bar.myPlugin` is an actual property instantiated from `foo`?

Simultaneously, `this instanceof foo`, ie. `jQuery instanceof jQuery` seems redundant.

What am I missing here? Appreciate any help/direction.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24019863/1048572 - in this case, what is `this` in `new foo()` vs in `foo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

`foo` is an constructor function and we ensure it's always invoked like so.

### explanation

`foo` is an constructor function. When called with `new` keyword the body of `foo` function will be executed in context of new instance of `foo` class (`this` will be pointing to this new instance). So:

```
this instanceof foo === true
```

When called **without** the `new` keyword the context will be `window`and normally no new object would be created.

Via

```
if (!(this instanceof foo))
  return new foo(arg);
```

we ensure that even if one omits `new` keyword we return new instance of `foo`.