# Prototypical inheritance and constructors

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I couldn't find anything matching my exact question so sorry if this is a duplicate.

Given the code:

```
var Foo = function () {
};

Foo.prototype.log = function (message) {
    console.log(message);
};

var Bar = function () {
};

Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
```

I can inherit the `log(message)` function of `Foo` within `Bar` and call the following code without issue.

```
var bar = new Bar();

bar.log("this works");
```

If I then move the assignment of the prototype to the constructor like follows:

```
var Foo = function () {
};

Foo.prototype.log = function (message) {
    console.log(message);
};

var Bar = function () {
    Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
};
```

The call to `log(message)` will fail

> TypeError: bar.log is not a function

Now I'm probably missing something obvious but why is this the case? How would I lazily inherit properties?

The use case I am imagining is inheriting objects from an asynchronously loaded JavaScript file, something like a `google.maps.OverlayView` whilst being able to already have the inherited object present in the page.

Comment: this.prototype might work instead of Bar.prototype

Comment: You cannot setup inheritance after having constructed instances already. Wait with that until the file is loaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this.constructor.prototype — can't wholly overwrite, but can write individual props?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21296559/1048572). It's not exactly your use case, but will answer the question why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sikorski: No it won't.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign the prototype within the constructor, it will be assigned *after* first instantiation. In the code snippet (or [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/7aLujbqh/) with a few more examples and inheritance check) that situation is demonstrated in `barfoo1` and `barfoo2`. A solution would be to *copy* `Foo.prototype` within the `Bar` constructor. Another solution is to return an instance on assigning the prototype within the constructor. Both are demonstrated in the `FooBar` and `FooFoo` constructor in the snippet respectively.

Furthermore you can assign the prototype just `using Xyz.prototype = Abc.prototype` (no need for `Object.create` here), or use `Xyz.prototype = new Abc`.

```js
var Foo = function () {};

Foo.prototype.log = function (msg) {
  log(msg);
}

var Bar = function () {
    Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
};

var FooBar = function () {
  if (!FooBar.prototype.log) {
     for (var l in Foo.prototype) {
       FooBar.prototype[l] = Foo.prototype[l];
     }
  }
}

var FooFoo = function () {
  if (!FooFoo.prototype.log) {
       FooFoo.prototype = new Foo;
       return new FooFoo;
    }
}

var BarFoo = function () {
  if (!BarFoo.prototype.log) {
       BarFoo.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
  }
}

var bar = new Bar;
var foobar = new FooBar;
var barfoo1 = new BarFoo; 
var barfoo2 = new BarFoo;
var doublefoo = new FooFoo;

try { bar.log('hello!'); }
catch(e) {log('bar.log failed =&gt; ', e.message);}

try { barfoo1.log('barfoo1 hello!'); }
catch(e) {log('barfoo1.log failed =&gt; ', e.message);}

try { barfoo2.log('barfoo2 hello!'); }
catch(e) {log('barfoo2.log failed =&gt; ', e.message);}

foobar.log('foobar just works (Foo.prototype copied)');
doublefoo.log('doublefoo just works too (instantiation on assigning Foo.prototype)');

function log() {
  document.querySelector('#result')
    .innerHTML += '<p>'+ [].slice.call(arguments).join('') +'</p>';
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: `Bar.prototype = Foo.prototype;` - wait what? That's not inheritance! (and makes as little sense as the original code *in* the constructor)

Comment: @Bergi *not inheritance*:  could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @KooiInc: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11088365/1048572) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/1048572) question elaborates quite well.

Comment: @Bergi: I don't read it's *not inheritance* in this and that. I only read it may be better to use `Object.create` for inheritance. Of which I am not sure (see also the jsfiddle within the answer).

Comment: @KooiInc: "*Then they both refer to the same object, so you might as well have everything in `Bar`, if you add something to `Foo.prototype`, it will be added to `Bar.prototype` as well. You can easily test it by adding something to `Foo.prototype` after the assignment. For example, in your case you can see that `Bar.prototype.constructor` is actually `Foo`*" (paraphrased class names). They are no distinct classes inheriting from each other any more when they have the same prototype object, but they are the same class.

Answer (score 0):

James if jQuery is possible in your code you could attempt something like this -

```
var Bar = function() {};
$.ajax({
  url: "http://maps.google.com/api/scriptfile.js",
  dataType: "script",
  success: function(script, status) {
             Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
           }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: please explain your answer, why is there an ajax call for this purpose ?

Comment: ajax is there because of the phrase in the question "asynchronously loaded JavaScript file". It could be achieved using - script tag in HTML. But loading a script file only when necessary using ajax is an alternative.