# how to inherit javascript anonymous functions assigned to variables?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Trying to understand inheritnace in javascript and totally confused

I just need that DogCat to have `bark` and `meow` function and able to access `this` (somehow) of each object in inheritance chain:

```
    var cat = function() { this.name = "tom"; this.cat_instance = this; }
    var dog = function() { this.name = "bob"; this.dog_instance = this; console.log("cat is here!");} 

    cat.prototype.meow = function() { console.log("mhew");  }
    dog.prototype.bark = function() { console.log("whoof"); }

    var DogCat = function() {
        DogCat.prototype = dog.prototype;
        DogCat.constructor = cat;
        console.log("my name is " + this.dog_instance + " " + this.cat_instance);   
    }
```

So `DogCat.prototype` now (should ?) point to `dog` prototype and in instance of `DogCat` I should able to get at least `bark` function but instance doesn't have this function.

Okay thats a mess (in my mind), I am try now apply both inherited constructors to a child:

```
    var DogCat = function() {
        cat.apply(this);
        dog.apply(this);
        console.log("my name is " + this.dog_instance + " " + this.cat_instance);   
    }
```

Then, point a prototype to a dog:

```
    DogCat.prototype = dog.prototype;
    var d = new DogCat();
    > cat is here!
    >my name is [object Object] [object Object]
```

Now I can access the `bark` but how to deal with `meow` function? How to build prototype chains properly?

**UPD**

sorry in `DogCat` there should be `DogCat.prototype = dog.prototype`, fixed

Comment: The first rule of prototypes is: [Never assign to them inside the constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21296559/1048572). The second rule of JS prototypes is: there is no [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out ! but how to build complex applications and avoid how to avoid code duplication ? just reassigning prototype properties like  `DogCat.prototype.meow = cat.prototype.meow;` ?

Comment: Yes, there are many more patterns to avoid code duplication than just inheritance. Which of them fits your situation best depends; if you show your real code we could suggest something.

Comment: No code to show as I am learning now, maybe you can suggest some book to read, (right now reading 'Stoyan Stefanov' javascript patterns) or some average-sized open source project to dig in and learn from?

Comment: Nah, nothing particular to recommend, everyone's style is a bit different. The most important lesson about patterns however is that [yagni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) - never use a pattern because you like it or have always used it, only use it when you *need* it. Start with object literals to create your objects, then add as required :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mostly on the right track but have some mistakes.

Your first code will not work because you assign the prototype inside the constructor, that means the prototype is assigned after the object is created. First created object wouldn't have the prototype methods but second one would. Also you already noticed assigning the `constructor` won't do any good. You have to apply constructors manually.

```
var DogCat = function() {
    cat.apply(this);
    dog.apply(this);
    console.log("my name is " + this.dog_instance + " " + this.cat_instance);
    }
DogCat.prototype = dog.prototype;
```

Prototypes are also just normal objects. No magical properties. You can't assign two prototypes and expect it to work magically. If you want to inherit from two base classes, you can write an `inherit` function for your convenience.

```
function copyPrototypeMethods(myClass,base){
    for(var prop in base.prototype){
        myClass.prototype[prop] = base.prototype[prop];
    }
}

// Use it like:
copyPrototypeMethods(DogCat, dog);
copyPrototypeMethods(DogCat, cat);
```

Or manually assign all the methods you need from base classes if you know what you are inheriting.

```
DogCat.prototype.bark = dog.prototype.bark;
DogCat.prototype.meow = cat.prototype.meow;
```

Comment: You shouldn't name that function `inheritFrom`. Instead, `copyPrototypeMethods` would be appropriate. The term "inheritance" implies that (with `d = new DogCat`) `d instanceof Dog` and `d instanceof Cat` would work, which they don't.