# how to define a custom method on the javascript object class

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I was going over [Javascript the good parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) and I came across this example, where the author was trying to explain how to be able to call a superclass:

```
Object.method('superior', function (name) {
    var that = this,
        method = that[name];
    return function (  ) {
        return method.apply(that, arguments);
    };
});
```

an example of using this code:

```
super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');
```

however chrome wouldn't recognize `method` on Object. I tried doing the same thing using [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) but that didn't work either.. any help?

**update**:
does this method cause any known conflicts with jQuery? As soon as i put the following at the first js file in my page:

I get this error in line 2062 in [jquery-1.11.0.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (name) {
    var that = this,
        method = that[name];
    return function (  ) {
        return method.apply(that, arguments);
    };
} has no method 'exec'
```

this is the effected code:

```
    // Filters
    for ( type in Expr.filter ) {
        if ( (match = matchExpr[ type ].exec( soFar )) && (!preFilters[ type ] ||
            (match = preFilters[ type ]( match ))) ) {
            matched = match.shift();
            tokens.push({
                value: matched,
                type: type,
                matches: match
            });
            soFar = soFar.slice( matched.length );
        }
    }
```

any idea what's going on?

Comment: Somewhere in that book he does define a custom `method` function. Use it!

Comment: @Bergi seems that using that messes up my jquery.. is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

The author of the book explains that for that piece of code to work you need to define the method function first:

`Throughout the book, a method method is used to define new methods. This is its definition:`

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
 this.prototype[name] = func;
 return this;
};
```

Comment: So that means one should actually never use `method` on `Object` to [avoid messing up the `Object.prototype`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi: Your question is unclear. `Object` has no method `method` by default. So to use it, you have to "mess" with the prototype. As the other question says: You need to be aware that people are changing the prototype, so use the proper loop construct.

Comment: `method` is a `Function` method, which means it does not mess up `Object.prototype`. Only applying it to `Object` will… As my answer to the other question says, changing the loop construct is *not* the solution.

Answer (score 2):

> seems that using that messes up my jquery.. is there a way to avoid it?

Yes. Redefine `Function.prototype.method` to

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
  Object.defineProperty(this.prototype, name, {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false, // sic!
    writable: true,
    value: func
  });
  return this;
};
```

before using it on the `Object` function (`Function.prototype.method` itself doesn't mess up jQuery, but calling `Object.method()` does). See also [How to define method in javascript on Array.prototype and Object.prototype so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572).

Comment: looks like u don't have an 80K+ score on SO for nothin'! anyways can you recommend me a *good* tutorial on how to call superclasses in javascript? been the very flexible language it is, it seems like everyone and their sister-in-law has an opinion on how to do anything.. I want something that's clear and time tested. The example in `javascript the good parts` is very elementary and basic, and doesn't fully address my situation.

Comment: I tend to `call` it explicitly, as [laid out here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16963189/1048572) :-) Works 100%, is flexible, yet a bit lengthy and could use some caching optimistions.