# Proper way to call superclass functions from subclass

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I have a "SuperClass" with "info" as an instance variable. "SuperClass" has function "printInfo()". "printInfo()" needs to access instance variable "info". 
I want to create a "SubClass" which also has method "printInfo()". I want to call printInfo() of "SuperClass" from "printInfo()" of "SubClass".

```
SuperClass = function()
{
    this.info = "I am superclass";
    console.log("SuperClass:");
};

SuperClass.prototype.printInfo = function(that)
{
    console.log("printing from superclass printInfo");
    console.log(that.info);
};

SubClass = function(){};

SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass();

SubClass.prototype.printInfo = function()
{
    console.log("calling superclass");
    this.constructor.prototype.printInfo(this);
    console.log("called superclass");
};

var sc = new SubClass();
sc.printInfo();
```

You can see that I am passing "that" as a parameter to printInfo. Without "that" parameter, "info" is printed as "undefined". Like in the following case, "this.info" is undefined when this function is called from object of "SubClass".

```
SuperClass.prototype.printInfo = function()
    {
        console.log("printing from superclass printInfo");
        console.log(this.info);
    };
```

What is the proper way to override and invoke methods of superclass in javascript, enabling functions to access instance variables of the class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Class Inheritance For Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963111/javascript-class-inheritance-for-functions)

Comment: and you should also [get your constructor inheritance correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898786/correct-javascript-inheritance/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are messing with the `SubClass`'s prototype with the `SuperClass`'s object, in this line

```
SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass();
```

the child's prototype should depend on the Parent's prototype. So, you can inherit like this

```
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);
```

Also, it is quite normal to change the constructor to the actual function, like this

```
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

To keep your implementation generic, you can use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf), to get the parent prototype in the inheritance chain and then invoke `printInfo`, like this

```
SubClass.prototype.printInfo = function() {
    Object.getPrototypeOf(SubClass.prototype).printInfo(this);
};
```

Since, `info` is defined in the `SubClass` yet, it will print `undefined`. You might also want to call the parent't constructor, like this

```
var SubClass = function() {
    SuperClass.call(this);
};
```

**Note:** You are creating global variables, by omitting `var` keyword before `SuperClass` and `SubClass`.

Comment: To keep it generic, I called super constructor with Object.getPrototypeOf(Subclass.prototype).constructor.call(this). That is same way you invoke the super class function. Although I am not sure if this is the correct way, I am no expert on how js works.

Comment: Wouldn't the call from `Subclass.printInfo()` to `Superclass.printInfo()` be `Object.getPrototypeOf(SubClass.prototype).printInfo.call(this)` rather than just `...printInfo(this)?` I ask because I tried it your way and got an error about `undefined`. I'm not a JS expert, so it's not clear to me why either way would work or not work.

Comment: @thefourtheye If you wanna be really clean you could say `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))`.

Comment: @GreatBigBore Correct. You need `.call(this)` so that `this` inside the called method will be the same as inside the calling method.

Answer (score 13):

```
class Thing {
  constructor(age) { this.age = age; }
  die(how) { console.log(`Died of ${how}`); }
}

class Me extends Thing {
  constructor() { super(59); console.log(`I am ${this.age}`); }
  // Refer to a method from the superclass that is overridden in the subclass
  die(how) { super.die('liver failure'); console.log(`while ${how}`) }
}

(new Me()).die('hang gliding');
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple and uses the new `class` syntax

Answer (score 10):

After reading all the answers, I am using the following inheritance mechanism:

```
var SuperClass = function()
{
    this.info = "I am superclass";
    console.log("SuperClass:");
};

SuperClass.prototype.printInfo = function()
{
    console.log("printing from superclass printInfo");
    console.log("printinfo");
    console.log(this.info);
};

var SubClass = function(){
    SuperClass.call(this);
};

SubClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

SubClass.prototype.printInfo = function()
{
    console.log("calling superclass");
    Object.getPrototypeOf(SubClass.prototype).printInfo.call(this);
    console.log("called superclass");
};

var sc = new SubClass();
sc.printInfo();
```

Comment: You need to set the constructor too, **SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass**

Answer (score 7):

You can write it like this :

```
SuperClass.prototype.printInfo = function(){
  console.log("printing from superclass printInfo");
  console.log(this.info); 
};

SubClass.prototype.printInfo = function(){
  console.log("calling superclass");
  SuperClass.prototype.printInfo.call(this);
  console.log("called superclass");
};
```

Answer (score 5):

For anybody who comes more from a Java world I would ignore all of the above and use  the following syntax instead that was introduced in 2015

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}

class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor(sideLength) {
    super(sideLength, sideLength);
  }
  get area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
  set sideLength(newLength) {
    this.height = newLength;
    this.width = newLength;
  }
}
```

More info on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

And suddently u can use super as keyword to access ancester etc.... For me finding this was a big relief

Comment: Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, `super` can only be used in the constructor.

Comment: Fortunately, @Offirmo is wrong. :-)  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

@coolscitist

Instead of

```
SubClass.prototype.printInfo = function()
{
    Object.getPrototypeOf(SubClass.prototype).printInfo.call(this);
};
```

use this

```
SubClass.prototype.printInfo = function()
{
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype).printInfo.call(this);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Only your solution worked for me. The other answers called the superclass method ok, but got undefined 'this' error.

Comment: No, this is not ok.  Let say a new class `Class3` inherit from `SubClass`, calling `Class3`'s printInfo() will cause infinite loop.  This is because the `this.constructor` above will always give `Class3` instead of `SubClass`, i.e. calling printInfo function of `Class3`'s superclass (SubClass) again & again.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to sort this out is to save the parent's function in different variable before overriding in the child class definition.

```
var Foo = function(){
    var self = this.
    this.init = function(a,b){
        self.a = a;
        seld.b = b;
    };
}

var Goo = function(){
    Foo.apply(this);
    var self = this;
    self.Foo = { init: self.init };//saves the super class's definition of init in a new variable
    self.init = function(a,b,c){
       self.Foo.init(a,b);//can call the super class function
       self.c = c;
    };
}

var a = new Foo();
a.init(1,2);
var b = new Goo();
b.init(1,2,3);
```