# Call a parent view's function in Marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

In Marionette, how might I go about calling a function of the same name on the parent object of a view without overwriting the original function?

For instance:

```
var someView = new Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    onRender: function () {
        console.log('foo');
    }
});

var anotherView = someView.extend({
    onRender: function () {

        // call someView's original onRender function

        console.log('bar');
    }
});

anotherView.render();
```

Resulting in the console output:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: So you don't mean the parent view (in the tree), but the `super` view from which you inherited?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `__super__`, which is set up by [`extend`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend):

```
var anotherView = someView.extend({
    onRender: function () {
        this.__super__.onRender.call(this);
        console.log('bar');
    }
});
```

or just directly reference the method that you want to apply on your instance:

```
var anotherView = someView.extend({
    onRender: function () {
        someView.prototype.onRender.call(this);
        console.log('bar');
    }
});
```

For more information, see [Javascript Class Inheritance For Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16963111/1048572) and [what `.call()` does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: upvote for your second example, in Marionette 2.0.0 at least the first example says undefined for super

Comment: Neither of these were working in Marionette 4.1.2.  Had to use this:  `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).onRender.call(this);`

Comment: @Briguy37 What error are you getting on the second one? Despite this answer being 8 years old, `Superclass.prototype.method.call` is an ageless solution that also works with ES6 classes. Does Marionette no longer use standard prototype inheritance?

Comment: @Bergi `this.prototype` was `undefined` when I debugged it as a watch in Chrome devtools, but the `[[Prototype]]` property was displayed on it, and accessible with the `Object.getPrototypeOf` from my previous comment.

Comment: @Bergi Now that I look at it and re-read my comments, I'm wondering if maybe I tried `this.prototype` rather than the `someView.prototype` approach.

Comment: @Briguy37 Yeah, `this.prototype` doesn't work, you need to use `someView.prototype`. I recommend to avoid `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` since it doesn't work if you further inherit from the class. A better alternative (closer to what `super` does in ES6 classes) is `Object.getPrototypeOf(anotherView.prototype).onRender.call(this, …)`.