# Prototype chain: call "super" method over multiple levels

Tags: javascript, oop, chaining, prototype-chain

I have got the following prototype chain

- SuperSuperClass

  - SuperClass

    - Class

each with a method named `do`.

What is the common approach for calling the respective super class method?
For the moment I use `<ClassName>.prototype.__proto__.<methodName>.call(this)` but that looks odd.

Using the following code the console prints (as expected):

- *Class.prototype.do*
- *SuperClass.prototype.do*
- *SuperSuperClass.prototype.do*

```
SuperSuperClass = function SuperSuperClass() {}
SuperSuperClass.prototype.do = function() {
    console.log('SuperSuperClass.prototype.do');
};

function SuperClass() {
    SuperSuperClass.call(this);
}
SuperClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperSuperClass.prototype);
SuperClass.prototype.constructor = SuperClass;
SuperClass.prototype.do = function() {
    console.log('SuperClass.prototype.do');
    SuperClass.prototype.__proto__.do.call(this);
};

function Class() {
    SuperClass.call(this);
}
Class.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);
Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
Class.prototype.do = function() {
    console.log('Class.prototype.do');
    Class.prototype.__proto__.do.call(this);
};

var objClass = new Class();
objClass.do();
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcaQ9/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the common approach for calling the respective super class method?

Use `<SuperClassName>.prototype.<methodName>.call(this)`. It's not only shorter, but also has the benefit of working in environments that don't support the non-standard `__proto__` property.

Comment: Aarg… I tried something similar before but used `ClassName` accidentally. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fcaQ9/1/  
Using `this.constructor.prototype.do.call(this)` as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18617418) is not a solution, is it?

Comment: [No, it's not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16105890/1048572) - imagine your `Class` does not overwrite `SuperClass::do`, you'll get infinite recursion similar to [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24700014/1048572)

Comment: Thank you for the references.