# Trying simple approach to OPP inheritance in Javascript (ES5)

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

Just for the sake of curiosity, I was playing with prototypal inheritance and OOP inheritance in Javascript. Most results involve emulating 'Class' and 'extends' concepts with functions, while others use the prototype and constructors.

I wrote this code:

```
function Warrior(weaponName) {
    var weapon = weaponName;
    this.getWeapon = function() {
        return weapon;
    };
    this.setWeapon = function(value) {
        weapon = value;
    };
    this.displayInfo = function() {
        return {
            "weapon": this.getWeapon(),
        };
    };
}

function Archer() {
    var accuracy = "86%";
    this.parent = Archer.prototype; // Inheritance workaround
    this.getAccuracy = function() {
        return accuracy;
    };
    this.setAccuracy = function(value) {
        accuracy = value;
    };
    this.displayInfo = function() {
        var form = this.parent.displayInfo();
        form.accuracy = this.getAccuracy();
        return form;
    };
}
Archer.prototype = new Warrior("bow");
var w = new Warrior("sword");
var a = new Archer();
console.log(w.displayInfo());
console.log(a.displayInfo());
```

I made this so when displaying the information from the Warrior class, it shows the object as

```
{ weapon: "sword" }
```

And when the information from Archer is shown, the object is:

```
{ weapon: "sword", accuracy: "86%" }
```

The "subclass" is taking information from the "superclass" and adding to it. Calling "getWeapon()" or "setWeapon" from Archer also works. The chain goes on without problems, even when I add a third class "Kyudoka" that extends "Archer" and has it's own properties as well.

But comparing to the more complex code I found while researching, I feel this could be a naive implementation (the "Inheritance workaround" line) and I'm missing something (considering that JS has a lot of subtlety).

This is a theorical question, I'm not using this code in any system.

Comment: You can use `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` instead of hardcoding the `Archer.prototype` as a property.

Comment: Every instance of the Warrior creates 3 function. So for example if you have 3 archers, then it will result in 300 function. By prototypal inheritance you create only 3 functions, no matter how many instances you have. There can be some optimization on this, I don't know.

Comment: This article helped me: [JavaScript object creation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/javascript-object-creation.html)

Comment: @WhiteHat - The problem with articles like that, is they over-complicate the essence of what they're trying to show you. He shows too many concepts for a perfunctory task.

Comment: @LyeFish - thanks! Less hardcoding is always good!

Comment: @inf3rno - think I could reduce the number of functions if I used <pre><code>Object.defineProperties()<pre><code>, I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: @WhiteHat - thanks for the reference

Comment: `Archer.prototype = new Warrior("bow");` is wrong, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/1048572/Benefits-of-using-Object.create-for-inheritance

Comment: You must not use a `this.parent` property like that. It won't work in subclasses of `Archer`, like [in this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24700014/1048572). Use a [correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25060720/1048572) [pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16105890/1048572)

Comment: @adrield Object.defineProperty is buggy. Good luck with it! Btw. you should use Object.create or at least create the descendant prototype with a different constructor.

Comment: @Bergi - a curious behaviour, "this.parent" actually worked with a third class in the chain without breaking the stack, but trying to put "parent" variable in the prototype blew up the whole thing on Chrome! Thanks for the links! :)
Edit: typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly 3 kinds of inheritance in *javascript*, according to the book *Javascript the Good Parts*: **Pseudoclassical**, **Prototypal** and **Functional**.

The one you just posted would fit under the **Pseudoclassical** inheritance, where you emulate a Class behaviour using constructor functions.

I find more useful and flexible the **Functional** pattern, which allows you to protect your variables (make them private).

```
var constructor = function (spec, my) {
  var that, other private instance variables;
  my = my || {};
  //Add shared variables and functions to my
  that = a new object;
  //Add privileged methods to that
  return that;
}
```

**Prototypal** is basically having your objects inherit directly from other useful object, which would be something like having them (the useful objects) as your new object constructor prototype.

```
Object.beget = function (o) {
  var F = function () {};
  F.prototype = o;
  return new F();
};

var a = {}
//Add shared variables to a
var b = Object.beget(a);
//Add new methods to b
```

That are many considerations to each of the patterns, for instance Crockford says in his book *"The functional pattern has a great deal of flexibility. It requires less effort than the pseudoclassical pattern,
and gives us better encapsulation and information hiding and access to super methods."*, but I've also seen articles arguing the other way around, such as this http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php

EDIT ------

In case you might want to know different aproaches to reaching super methods, in the **Functional** pattern you can do the following:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this;
};

Object.method('superior', function (name) {
  var that = this,
  method = that[name];
  return function ( ) {
    return method.apply(that, arguments);
  };
});

var archer = function (spec, accuracy) {
  var that = warrior(spec),
  super_displayInfo = that.superior('displayInfo');
  that.getAccuracy = function() {
    return accuracy;
  };
  that.setAccuracy = function(value) {
    accuracy = value;
  };
  that.displayInfo = function (n) {
    var form = super_displayInfo()
    form.accuracy = that.getAccuracy();
    return form;
  };
  return that;
};
```

Comment: thanks! indeed, "Pseudoclassical" sound more like I was going for. I was putting some thought on private variables in this setup. 

By default, I would only use "var varable_name" inside the "class" and then expose it as needed with Object,defineProperty / Object,defineProperties getters and setters. I still have to fiddle a bit more with the idea, I guess it would not cover the "protected" variable cases.

Comment: No problem! I added an different workaround to reaching superior methods if you are interested =)

Answer (score 2):

Put the functions on the prototype...

```
function Warrior(weaponName) {
    this.weapon = weaponName;
}

Warrior.prototype = {

    getWeapon : function() {
        return this.weapon;
    },

    setWeapon : function(value) {
        this.weapon = value;
    },

    displayInfo : function() {
        return { "weapon" : this.getWeapon() };
    }
};

//----------------------------------

function Archer(weaponName) {
    Warrior.call(this, weaponName);
    this.accuracy = "86%";
}

Archer.prototype = Object.create(Warrior.prototype);
Archer.prototype.constructor = Archer;

Archer.prototype.getAccuracy = function() {
    return this.accuracy;
};

Archer.prototype.setAccuracy = function(value) {
    this.accuracy = value;
};

Archer.prototype.displayInfo = function() { 
    return "weapon: " + this.getWeapon() + ", accuracy: " + this.getAccuracy();
};


//----------------------------------

var w = new Warrior("sword");
var a = new Archer("axe");
console.log(w.displayInfo()); // Object {weapon: "sword"}
console.log(a.displayInfo()); // weapon: axe, accuracy: 86%
```

Edit: fixed recursion

Comment: Your implementation of `displayInfo` on the `Archer` creates infinite recursion because it doesn't call `Weapon.displayInfo`.

Comment: @Mike C - well spotted, I just copied the OP code without going into the minuatia.

Comment: @Data - thanks for the insight on prototypal!
I understand that I could just override the Archers' displayInfo() with the data I need, but I was trying to come up with a way to actually use the 'super' method. But I will try a bit with the Object.create and the constructor, as you described and see what happens!

Comment: @adrield - I wouldn't bother with things like `super`, it doesn't fit with JS prototypal structure. You create objects with own properties and link the prototype to another prototype . JS can only look down the chain and not up, so trying to hack a super reference defeats the goal of prototypal inheritance/delegation.